# Get distinct Posts with multiple tags and tag followers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to implement the "Follow Tag" feature in Stackoverflow

I have the following structure for it:

```
POSTS TABLE
----------
POSTS_ID
POSTS_TAGS (XML COMMA SEPARATED LIST)



POSTTAGS TABLE
------------
 POSTTAGS_ID
 POSTTAGS_TAGS_ID
 POSTTAGS_POSTS_ID



TAGS TABLE
----------
TAGS_ID
TAGS_NAME



TAGFOLLOW
----------
TAGFOLLOW_ID
TAGFOLLOW_USERS_ID
TAGFOLLOW_TAGS_ID
TAGFOLLOW_APP_ID
```

I Thought the query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSTS P 
JOIN POSTTAGS PT ON PT.POSTTAGS_POST_ID = P.POSTS_ID
JOIN TAGFOLLOW F ON F.TAGFOLLOW_TAGS_ID = PT.POSTTAGS_TAGS_ID
WHERE F.TAGFOLLOW_USERS_ID = 12236
```

How do I get the Distinct Post?
I have tried the distinct function but no luck yet. 
The above query returns a post record with tag that the user is subscribed to. So when a user is subscribed to more than one tag that is on the post, the query returns that many duplicate records.

I hope its something simple I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return only columns from `POSTS` and use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.POSTS_ID, P.POSTS_TAGS
FROM POSTS P 
JOIN POSTTAGS PT ON PT.POSTTAGS_POST_ID = P.POSTS_ID
JOIN TAGFOLLOW F ON F.TAGFOLLOW_TAGS_ID = PT.POSTTAGS_TAGS_ID
WHERE F.TAGFOLLOW_USERS_ID = 12236
```

Alternatively, you can use an `IN`

```
SELECT P.POSTS_ID, P.POSTS_TAGS
FROM POSTS P
WHERE P.POSTS_ID IN
(
    SELECT PT.POSTTAGS_POST_ID FROM POSTTAGS PT
    JOIN TAGFOLLOW F ON F.TAGFOLLOW_TAGS_ID = PT.POSTTAGS_TAGS_ID
    WHERE F.TAGFOLLOW_USERS_ID = 12236
)
```

Comment: What about using a CTE and then joining on top of your original?

Comment: Why should you complicate something simple though?

Comment: There is a lot more that I am pulling with it.  User repuations, Post Votes, Answered status. Along with adding rowcount for pagination.

Comment: Then sure, go for it. You can use the query above in any manner you like. Can't tell you more as I don't know your exact requirement.